# Illegal mix of collations for operation 'like' with PDO bindValue()

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, collation, mysql-error-1267

I changed my code from mysql_query to pdo prepare(), bindValue() and execute()

but with the new code, when I bind Hebrew values to :t0 for the query

```
select * from product where ( prd_name_HEB like :t0 or prd_code like :t0 )
```

I get

```
General error: 1267 Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (hebrew_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation 'like'
```

- prd_code collation is latin1_swedish_ci
- prd_name_HEB collation is hebrew_general_ci
- :t0 collation is unknown.

I cannot alter my whole DB to utf8_unicode_ci now.

I understand that I can use COLLATE in my query to set the collation, but I do not know where to add it.

1. Please let me know what is the correct syntax, with "like" and "COLLATE" for the following query:

   select * from product where ( prd_name_HEB like :t0 or prd_code like :t0 )
2. Is there a way to add collation to PDO bindValue() ?

Thanks.

Comment: How to add collation to string - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-literal.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved:

```
if searchString.containsHebrewCharacters()
  select * from product where ( prd_name_HEB like :t0 )
else
  select * from product where ( prd_name_HEB like :t0 or prd_code like :t0 )
```